# Qt : pass values from a window to another

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt App running two windows, a login window and a data window. I need to be able to pass a couple of values from the first to the second, but i can't figure out a way to do it, since - on my main.cpp file - i have :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    LoginWindow loginWindow;
    loginWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

What i'd want would be :

```
LoginWindow loginWindow; 
loginWindow.who();

// wait for user to input data in LoginWindow.......

// fetch datas from loginWindow

SecondWindow secondWindow; 
secondWindow.show();
```

So, as soon as my LoginWindow is closed (after the login), the whole app is terminated. Plus, i can't extract datas drom LoginWindow to the main function, since i don't know when they'll be available. 
How can i make this work ?

Thanks.

Comment: I only see one window declared in your code.  How is the data window launched?

Comment: Well at the moment i declare the second window on the first one's code, i'll edit the code to be a little more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would declare a local variable in `Main()` and pass it by-reference to the login window's constructor, i.e.:

```
string username;
LoginWindow loginwindow(username);
loginwindow.show();
```

Where the constructor is declared like this:

```
LoginWindow::LoginWindow(string& username);
```

Then `LoginWindow` can modify the string however it needs to, and when the call to `show()` returns, the user name will be stored in the local variable `username`.  You can then pass that to the constructor of `secondWindow` in the same way.

Comment: This will work, however i can't handle the "wait for the infos to be filled", since the show() method don't "pause" the execution of the main function, unless i'm wrong ?

Comment: You can call the `exec()` method instead (as long as your login window inherits from `QDialog`), which will halt execution until the window is closed.

Answer (score 5):

That's a proper place for Qt's signals and slots. The simplest way to get going - just add one signal to LoginWindow class and one slot to DataWindow class:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    LoginWindow loginWindow;
    DataWindow dataWindow;

    QObject::connect(&loginWindow, SIGNAL(loginAcquired(LoginData)),
                     &dataWindow, SLOT(getLoginData(LoginData)));
    QObject::connect(&loginWindow, SIGNAL(loginAcquired(LoginData)),
                     &dataWindow, SLOT(show()));

    loginWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: That's elegant and would work, however i'd need a way to hide dataWindow untill the signal is received, i know no ways to do so, the QDialog::hide() method just do nothing ...

Comment: The show() slot can be triggered by any signal including custom loginAcquired(LoginData)